# How to not remove but handle outliers by transforming using pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, outliers

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
dfx = pd.DataFrame({'min_temp' :[-138,36,34,38,237,339]})
```

As you can see below that there are three outliers in this data `-138`,`237` and `239`

What I would like to do is identify records

a) which are greater than `3 standard deviation` and replace them with the valid maximum value(considering the data range).

b) which are lesser than `-3 standard deviation` and replace them with the valid minimum value(considering the data range).

This is what I tried but it is incorrect and not efficient

```
dfx.apply(lambda x: x[(x < dfx[min_temp].mean()-3*dfx[min_temp].std(), dfx[min_temp].mean()+3*dfx[min_temp].std())])
```

In the above example, 38 is the maximum value as it's within the `3sd` limit and a valid maximum value (meaning not outlier). Similarly 36 is minimum value as it's within the `-3sd`

We need to use this to replace all the outliers in full dataframe.

Please note in my real data, I have more than 60 columns and 1 Million rows. I would like to do this across all the columns. Any efficient and scalable approach is helpful

I expect my output to be like this? you can see how the outliers are replaced with `maximum valid value within 3sd (38 in this case)`

[image]

Can you help me with this?

**update after suggested solution**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based on the information in [this](http://colingorrie.github.io/outlier-detection.html) good article about outlier detection. You can read about each method there.
The output of each code shows the resulting lower and upper bounds for the outlier detection.

First, let's define some sample data:

```
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': np.random.normal(loc=20, scale=2, size=10)})

# Insert outliers
df['col1'][0] = 40
df['col1'][1] = 0

df['col1']
```

Output:

```
0    40.000000
1     0.000000
2    19.218962
3    16.648512
4    21.444715
5    22.637459
6    21.016641
7    22.527376
8    20.502631
9    20.715458
Name: col1, dtype: float64
```

## The Z-score method

This method is the least robust of all 3. It does not work well for small datasets (mean and standard deviation are heavily affected by outliers).

```
def cap_outliers(series, zscore_threshold=3, verbose=False):
    '''Caps outliers to closest existing value within threshold (Z-score).'''
    mean_val = series.mean()
    std_val = series.std()

    z_score = (series - mean_val) / std_val
    outliers = abs(z_score) > zscore_threshold

    series = series.copy()
    series.loc[z_score > zscore_threshold] = series.loc[~outliers].max()
    series.loc[z_score < -zscore_threshold] = series.loc[~outliers].min()

    # For comparison purposes.
    if verbose:
            lbound = mean_val - zscore_threshold * std_val
            ubound = mean_val + zscore_threshold * std_val
            print('\n'.join(
                ['Capping outliers by the Z-score method:',
                 f'   Z-score threshold: {zscore_threshold}',
                 f'   Lower bound: {lbound}',
                 f'   Upper bound: {ubound}\n']))

    return series

cap_outliers(df['col1'], verbose=True)
```

Output:

```
Capping outliers by the Z-score method:
   Z-score threshold: 3
   Lower bound: -8.28385086324063
   Upper bound: 49.22620154113844

0    40.000000
1     0.000000
2    19.218962
3    16.648512
4    21.444715
5    22.637459
6    21.016641
7    22.527376
8    20.502631
9    20.715458
Name: col1, dtype: float64
```

## The Modified Z-score method

This method is much more robust than the previous one. It uses median and mad instead of mean and std.

```
def cap_outliers(series, zscore_threshold=3, verbose=False):
    '''Caps outliers to closest existing value within threshold (Modified Z-score).'''
    median_val = series.median()
    mad_val = series.mad() # Median absolute deviation

    z_score = (series - median_val) / mad_val
    outliers = abs(z_score) > zscore_threshold

    series = series.copy()
    series.loc[z_score > zscore_threshold] = series.loc[~outliers].max()
    series.loc[z_score < -zscore_threshold] = series.loc[~outliers].min() 

    # For comparison purposes.
    if verbose:
            lbound = median_val - zscore_threshold * mad_val
            ubound = median_val + zscore_threshold * mad_val
            print('\n'.join(
                ['Capping outliers by the Modified Z-score method:',
                 f'   Z-score threshold: {zscore_threshold}',
                 f'   Lower bound: {lbound}',
                 f'   Upper bound: {ubound}\n']))

    return series

cap_outliers(df['col1'], verbose=True)
```

Output:

```
Capping outliers by the Modified Z-score method:
   Z-score threshold: 3
   Lower bound: 5.538418022763285
   Upper bound: 36.19368140628174

0    22.637459
1    16.648512
2    19.218962
3    16.648512
4    21.444715
5    22.637459
6    21.016641
7    22.527376
8    20.502631
9    20.715458
Name: col1, dtype: float64
```

## The IQR method

This method is the most strict of all 3.

```
def cap_outliers(series, iqr_threshold=1.5, verbose=False):
    '''Caps outliers to closest existing value within threshold (IQR).'''
    Q1 = series.quantile(0.25)
    Q3 = series.quantile(0.75)
    IQR = Q3 - Q1

    lbound = Q1 - iqr_threshold * IQR
    ubound = Q3 + iqr_threshold * IQR

    outliers = (series < lbound) | (series > ubound)

    series = series.copy()
    series.loc[series < lbound] = series.loc[~outliers].min()
    series.loc[series > ubound] = series.loc[~outliers].max()

    # For comparison purposes.
    if verbose:
            print('\n'.join(
                ['Capping outliers by the IQR method:',
                 f'   IQR threshold: {iqr_threshold}',
                 f'   Lower bound: {lbound}',
                 f'   Upper bound: {ubound}\n']))

    return series

cap_outliers(df['col1'], verbose=True)
```

Output:

```
Capping outliers by the IQR method:
   IQR threshold: 1.5
   Lower bound: 15.464630871041477
   Upper bound: 26.331958943979345

0    22.637459
1    16.648512
2    19.218962
3    16.648512
4    21.444715
5    22.637459
6    21.016641
7    22.527376
8    20.502631
9    20.715458
Name: col1, dtype: float64
```

## Conclusion

You should probably use the IQR method.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Upvoted. Will try and update you

Comment: Hi, you missed the `min` condition. I mean any values less than `-3sd` should be replaced with `min` value and any values greater than `+3sd` should be replaced with `max` value. I updated the post as well

Comment: @SSMK That makes sense. Please see the edited answer.

Comment: Hi, I tried this. It looks like it doesn't replace minimum values.You can try in the sample data as well

Comment: I guess we need to have a condition for `-3sd` as well

Comment: @SSMK I have tested the code and it seems to behave correctly for all outliers. There is already a line that replaces the outliers with negative deviation.

Comment: @SSMK Also please note that the code does not guarantee that the output series will have no outliers. When replacing the current outliers the standard deviation of the series drops which can generate new outliers by the same relative criteria.

Comment: @SSMK I have edited the answer to add two additional, more robust methods. Please try them.

Comment: Hi @Juan Estevez - Thanks for your detailed response. Much useful. Appreciate it

Comment: @JuanEstevez, I think there's a mistake in the modified z-score computation.
You are using pandas .mad() method, but that does not return the _median_ absolute deviation. It returns the _mean_ absolute deviation: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mad.html

Comment: Also, for the modified z-score we will have to add a constant term, which depends on the assumption of the underlying data. To assume a normal distribution, we can obtain modified z-scores through either: `zscore=(−̃ )/(∗MAD)` (with `k= 1.4826`), or through `zscore=f*(−̃ )/(MAD)`, with `f= 0.6745`. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/524089.
Please note that this also alters the `lbound` and `ubound` variables.

Comment: Proposed fix:
```from scipy.stats import median_abs_deviation```
Then
```mad_val = median_abs_deviation(series)```
```z_score = (series - median_val) / (1.486 * mad_val)```

And alter `lbound` and `ubound`: 
```lbound = median_val - zscore_threshold * (1.486 * mad_val)```
and
```ubound = median_val + zscore_threshold * (1.486 * mad_val)```

Alternatively, you could set mad_value to ```median_abs_deviation(series, scale='normal')``` and remove the constant from upper and lower bound, but this may be confusing to some.

Somehow I cannot get this code in a nice code block..

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generalized function which follows the following logic tot detect **non** outliers.

This function takes a dataframe as argument, so make sure you have numeric columns only.

> for each data point X: `abs(X - mean) <= (std * 3)`

Or in words:

> `residual <=  3*std`

```
def replace_outliers(df, n_std):

    outliers = df.sub(df.mean()).abs().le(df.std().mul(n_std))
    outliers_nan = df.where(outliers)

    outliers_replaced = outliers_nan.fillna(outliers_nan.max())

    return outliers_replaced
```

**Test**:

```
dfx = pd.DataFrame({'min_temp' : [10,12,12,13,12,11,14,13,15,10,10,10,100,12,14,13]})

# replaces 100 with 15
replace_outliers(dfx, 3)
```

Comment: thanks for the response. UUpvoted. will update soon. traveling

Comment: Actually I don't have a dataframe with numerical columns only. It has all types of columns. `string`, `categorical`,`integer` etc